# How to set Knex date to 30 days in the future

Tags: node.js, database-migration, knex.js

I think this question is simple really but I wasn't able to find an answer for it.

In Knex i could set a timestamp in my database with `knex.fn.now()`
However now I have a need to set a date 30 days after `now` is this as simple as `knex.fn.now() + 30` work or is there another trick?

Any help is appreciated even a link to a different source.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`knex.fn.now()` will execute `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function on the db, which returns timestamp in **ms** from 1/1/1970.

You can use a db built in method for calculating future dates.
In **MySQL** this method calls [`date_add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

```sql
SELECT date_add(now(), INTERVAL 30 day);
```

With Knex you will need to use the `raw` method.

```
knex.select(knex.raw('date_add(?, INTERVAL ? day)', [knex.fn.now(), 30]));
```

Edit:

In postgress, this query will look like:

```sql
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day';
```

so, in Knex it will be:

```
knex.select(knex.raw(`? + INTERVAL '? day'`, [knex.fn.now(), 30]));
```

Comment: could you show me how to do this raw query for postgresql

Comment: I've added a postgres example

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the previous answer, but that Postgresql example didn't work for me.

When I tried `` knex.raw(`? + INTERVAL '? day'`, [knex.fn.now(), 30]) ``, I got an error `"could not determine data type of parameter"`

This worked:

```
knex.raw(`? + ?::INTERVAL`, [knex.fn.now(), '30 day'])
```